# how to convert js object to js literal?

Tags: javascript, json, literals

I am using nodejs. I have an object.

```
const objA = { key : 'value' };
```

the target is to generate a new file obja.js, with the same literals inside the file, not JSON literal.
How can I achieve this?
If I use

```
let result = JSON.stringfy(objA);
```

result would be a JSON literal:

```
{ "key" : "value" }
```

But I want a js literals:

```
{ key : 'value' }
```

Comment: You can write your own stringifier, not difficult, or fix the results of JSON.stringify to remove quotes around property names. But you'll need to test the names first to ensure they're valid identifiers and keep quotes around those that aren't. BTW, an object that is created from a string literal has no idea of the formatting of the string that created it (e.g. double or single quotes, quoting of property names, etc.).

Comment: Why does it make any difference if it has quotes or not?

Answer (score 1):

You can use util here, its also handy when you want to console.log any object

```
const objA = { keyword : 'value' };
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util')
const objA1 = util.inspect(objA, {showHidden: false, depth: null})
fs.writeFileSync('./obja.js', objA1 );
```